# How can i tell if a Microsoft Outlook email is authentic?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Someone in my office said they sent me 3 emails a few months ago but I never saw any of them.  I then asked them to prove that they sent them.  I received copies of the 3 "emails" but their name was not printed at the top left corner nor was there the black line running horizontally across the page under their name.  That section was blank and then the rest of the paper had the usual Date, From, To, Subject etc...

If these were authentic emails sent to me from Outlook wouldn't the sender's name be printed at the top left in bold with the black line underneath just like all of my emails that I print off from my computer at work?  Those 3 "emails" look like they could have been printed in Word with the signature line and disclaimer at the bottom copy/pasted onto the Word doc.

Shouldn't those 3 emails have his name in bold with the black line underneath like every other printed email format?

Comment: If you did not receive them there is no way to prove you did get them or not.

Answer (score 3):

Ask your systems administrator.  If your mail server is logging mail, and the logs go that far back, he should be able to determine if, when, to, from, etc.